# Mail security on a shared server

Tags: centos, certificates, exim

I have a shared server with multiple user on it. I'm trying to secure their E-mail connection with a wild card certificate.

I added the key in `/etc/exim.key` and the certificate bundle in `/etc/exim.cert`. Restarted Exim and dovecot. And on a secure@mailaccount.tld everything worked fine.

But, there's always a but, the existing users have setup `mail.domainname`, through the non-secure ports(25/143/587).

When I had setup this, users complained that Apple Mail was giving them certificate errors, en they could not click away.

Which does not make sense, because when I `openssl s_client -connect` on domainname: 25/143/587, it shows a certificate not found error.

On port 993/995/465 is showed the Wild card certificate.

EDIT:

Apple Mail users port 993 by default, which you can change during account creation. Only after...

How can I enable Mail security through a certificate without hindering the existing non-secure Mail client configuration for my users?

System information

- CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511 (Core)
- DirectAdmin
- Exim 4.83